# How to join 3 models using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 models

**A**: `id`

**B**: `a_id`, `c_id`

**C**: `id`

and the model class

```
class A extends Model
{
    public function cs()
    {
        return ??
    }
}
```

How can I use Eloquent to retrieve all **C** models related to **A** using the intermediate model **B**?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish... Did you take a look at [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)? You should add a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

lets change you `a,b,c` to `member,group,and group_member`

it's called Many - to -Many Relation
member= _id
group = _id
group_member = group_id,mem_id

now in member model define

```
public function group(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Model\Group', 'group_member', 'mem_id','group_id');
}
```

so you can rterive  group of member

```
using Model\Member::with('group')->find($member_id);
```

same thing can you done in group model